# How do you hide a bucket column in a Kibana datatable

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Using Kibana 7.6.1.
I have a data table visualization with some information about docker containers. There is a terms bucket splitting the data on "container.id". I do however not want to show the container id in the table - it is not informational in my current context.
How do I use a field to split the data into rows, without showing that field in the table?

I.e. The column "theid" in the example below should not be visible:

[image]